# get input value and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field and I want to get input value when input loses focus ( if input is empty ) or just get input value ( if input isn't empty  )

My input

```
<input type="text"  id="title" value="Value test" kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on">
```

And I try

```
var input_length=$.trim($("#title").val());

function blurTitleValue() {
    $('#title').blur(function() {
        var str = $.trim($("#title").val());
        var str_ref = str.substring(0,3);
        return str_ref;
    });
}
function TitleValue() {
    var str = $.trim($("#title").val());;
    var str_ref = str.substring(0,3);
    return str_ref;
}
if(input_length.length>0)
{
    TitleValue();
}
else{
    blurTitleValue();
}
alert(str_ref);
```

But I can't get str_ref value

Comment: Im like 99% sure that alert(str_ref) will be undefined. You need to declare str_ref global and then assign value to it with functions. In your case you declare it localy inside function scope and after function exited you will not have str_ref variable.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk: Close -- it'll be a `ReferenceError` because it's trying to read the value of an undeclared identifier.

Comment: Yeah...forget about this :D... But the answer still correct. Ty for correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return `str_def` you are not setting variable `str_def` of parent scope to its value, you are just losing your value because you didn't assign it to anything. You need to save returned value to your variable.

Try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8emgkq97/1/).

```
<script>
    var input_length = $.trim($("#title").val());
    var str_ref;

    function blurTitleValue() {
        return $('#title').blur(function () {
            var str = $.trim($("#title").val());
            var str_ref1 = str.substring(0, 3);
            str_ref = str_ref1;
        });
    }

    function TitleValue() {
        var str = $.trim($("#title").val());
        ;
        var str_ref1 = str.substring(0, 3);
        return str_ref1;
    }
    if (input_length.length > 0) {
        str_ref = TitleValue();
    } else {
        blurTitleValue();
    }
    alert(str_ref);
</script>
```

Comment: Note that `blurTitleValue` never returns anything. And I'd avoid suggesting shadowing the variable like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I really didn't pay atention. But anyway, I think OP undertood it. I edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a global *str_ref* variable. You need to declare it globally, and **remove** the `var` before declaring str_ref inside the functions. It will scope the variable to the function and when trying to access *str_ref*, you will be trying to access the global variable (which in your case, is *undefined*).

Here is the fixed code:

```
var str_ref;

var input_length = $.trim($("#title").val());

function blurTitleValue() {
  $('#title').blur(function() {
    var str = $.trim($("#title").val());
    str_ref = str.substring(0, 3);
    return str_ref;
  });
}

function TitleValue() {
  var str = $.trim($("#title").val());;
  str_ref = str.substring(0, 3);
  return str_ref;
}


if (input_length.length > 0) {
  TitleValue();
} else {
  blurTitleValue();
}

alert(str_ref);
```

And a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxvrtkxj/).

It also unclear what you were trying to do with `blurTitleValue()`. Either way, you won't be able to access the new *str_ref* because it will only change on `blur`.

I would also recommend **caching** your jQuery elements.
Instead of always querying `$('#title')`, declare a global `var $title = $('#title');` and use it afterwards. This is best practice.

Comment: Why do you return `str_ref`? It doesn't affect anything.

Comment: That is the code provided by the asker. I only fixed the essentials.